# How to add QPushButton in QTableView when loading database by C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a chat application. In the chat view, where I show the chat messages using a QTableView, I want to add a QPushButton next to each message. Example:

```
A: How are you ? --- Button
B: I am fine --- Button
```

But I want to add only 10 rows. When scrolling, the data will change in the 10 rows, but I don't want to create new rows. And I want to know how to put the QPushButtons into the QTableView. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to know how to put the QPushButtons into the QTableView

You can achieve this using [setIndexWidget ( const QModelIndex & index, QWidget * widget )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) member function. Something like:

```
QTableView * table = new QTableView (this);
...
int column = 1;
for (int row = 0; row < 10; ++row) {
    QPushButton *  button = new QPushButton (tr("Button Name"), table);
    table->setIndexWidget (model->index (row, column, QModelIndex () ), button);
}
```